# Using Torrents and Tor simultaneously on the same machine

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, bittorrent

I know that even official Tor project website clearly says that it's bad idea to use torrents **over** Tor.

Just want to clarify.
If I understand correctly, to run torrents over Tor I have to run TBB and then specify in Torrent Client to use SOCKS5 proxy (IP and port of the machine which runs TBB for example `127.0.0.1:9150` if I run both apps on the same machine.)

Do I compromise my anonymity in any way if I just run TBB and Transmission(without using SOCKS proxy) on the same machine simultaneously?

My network is behind the NAT (just in case it makes any difference)